# Log4PostSharp project by inheriting from the ready-made (and working) custom attribute

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, aop, postsharp, log4postsharp

Need to modify Log4PostSharp project by inheriting from the ready-made (and working) custom attribute. It looks similar to this:

```
  [AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Module | AttributeTargets.Struct,
    AllowMultiple = true,
    Inherited = false)]
  [MulticastAttributeUsage(
  MulticastTargets.InstanceConstructor | MulticastTargets.StaticConstructor | MulticastTargets.Method,
    AllowMultiple = true)]
#if SILVERLIGHT
  [RequirePostSharp("Log4PostSharp", "Log4PostSharp.Weaver.SilverlightLogTask")]
#else
  [RequirePostSharp("Log4PostSharp", "Log4PostSharp.Weaver.LogTask")]
  [Serializable]
#endif
  public sealed class LogWithExceptionAttribute : LogAttribute
  {
    public LogWithExceptionAttribute()
    {
      ExceptionLevel = LogLevel.Error;
    }

    ...
  }
```

This is how I've chosen to annotate some unit-test code:

```
[LogWithException]
private void DoThrowException()
{
  throw new Exception("test exception");
}
```

Wanted to try to debug the compile-time process, tried to compile from the command line but couldn't get any hint:

```
> msbuild Log4PostSharp.Test.csproj /p:PostSharpBuild=Diag /p:PostSharpTrace="AssemblyBinding;Project" /v:detailed
```

Which is the right way to tackle the problem? What is the wrong thing I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Log4PostSharp.Weaver.LogTask::ProvideAdvice()` there was a following line: `var customAttributeEnumerator = customAttributeDictionaryTask.GetAnnotationsOfType(typeof(LogAttribute), true);`. The second attribute of `GetAnnotationsOfType()` was `false`, meaning that only `LogAttribute` annotations should be discovered. Changing it to `true` caused all the descendants of `LogAttribute` (including my `LogWithExceptionAttribute`) to be considered.